# ReactJS: Array of states - uncontrolled input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building component with multiple checkboxes - each for a category.

When I have only one checkbox in boolean var, it works perfectly(similar like in [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html)), but when I put states in an array, I'm getting the uncontrolled form warning:

> react.js:20541 Warning: CheckComponent is changing a controlled input of >type checkbox to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from >controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a >controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the >component.

Component:

```
handleChange: function(e) {
    this.props.onUserInput(
        this.refs[e.target.name].checked
    );
},
render: function(){
    var self = this;
    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                categories.map(function(d, i){
                    return (
                            <li key = {d}>
                                <input type="checkbox" checked={self.props.checkedBox[i]} name={d} ref={d} onChange={self.handleChange}/>
                                <span> {d} </span>
                            </li>
                        );
                })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Parent component:

```
getInitialState: function(){
  return{
      checkedBox: [true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true]
  };  
},
handleUserInput: function(checkedBox) {
    this.setState({
        checkedBox: checkedBox
    });
},
render: function(){
    return(
        <div>
            <CheckComponent checkedBox={this.state.checkedBox} onUserInput={this.handleUserInput} categories={this.props.categories}/>
            <DisplayComponent checkedBox={this.state.checkedBox} data={this.props.data}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Is something wrong with this array?

Comment: Have you looked at using a library to take care of it for you? react-checkbox-group already takes care of maintaining the state of your checkboxes and can be used both as a controlled and uncontrolled component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing array in your state with single value.
Just pass checkbox index to onChange function.

```
handleChange: function(i) {
    this.props.onUserInput(i);
},

...

<input type="checkbox" checked={self.props.checkedBox[i]} name={d} ref={d} onChange={function() {self.handleChange(i);}}/>
```

Then in your user input just change value at specified index.

```
handleUserInput: function(i) {
    this.setState({
        checkedBox: this.state.checkedBox.map(function(val, idx) {
                        if (idx === i) return !val; 
                        return val;
                    );
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a 'value' attribute in your input element. [React Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) says

> An  without a value property is an uncontrolled component

```
render: function() {
    return <input type="text" />;
}
```

> This will render an input that starts off with an empty value. Any
>   user input will be immediately reflected by the rendered element. If
>   you wanted to listen to updates to the value, you could use the
>   onChange event just like you can with controlled components.
>
> An uncontrolled component maintains its own internal state.

Comment: I have onChange event and everything works fine unless I'll make multiple checkboxes instead of single. When state is in boolean var it works, similar like in [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) example. Problem starts, when I'll make multiple inputs and the state is in array of booleans.

Comment: Actually he has it right - `checked, supported by <input> components of type checkbox or radio.` Please post your `handleChange` method.

Comment: `handleChange: function(e) {
        this.props.onUserInput(
            this.refs[e.target.name].checked
        );
    }`

And in parent component I have functions for initializing and setting state.

Comment: Please post this in your original question. Also onUserInput and init functions will be great.